# Do instantiated objects of the same class add to memory (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game for fun and had a question about c# performance.

I have two methods of doing the same task (below).  I prefer Method 2, but I am worried about instantiating a class (`PlayerMover`) for each player (perhaps 100 players).  Will it then keep 100 copies of `PlayerMover` in memory (one for each player)?  In my examples below I only instantiate `PlayerMover`, but in reality it could be 10 different classes per player (`PlayerSpawner`, `PlayerDespawner`, etc.).

**Method 1**

```cs
class Player {
}
```

```cs
class Game {
    private PlayerMover _mover;
    private List<Player> _players;

    public Game() {
        _mover = new PlayerMover();
    }

    public void tick() {
        foreach (Player player in _players) {
            _mover.Move(player);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```cs
class Player {
    private PlayerMover _mover;

    public Player() {
        _mover = new PlayerMover();
    }

    public void Move() {
        _mover.Move(this);
    }
}
```

```cs
class Game {
    private List<Player> _players;

    public void tick() {
        foreach (Player player in _players) {
            player.Move(player);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're asking whether the `new` operator will consume some memory each time, then yes, it will. On a side note, in Method2 you probably should pass the Player to the PlayerMover's constructor and then call `_mover.Move()` without parameters.

Comment: As far as I know, new instantiations of a single class only keep field data in memory (which are the property values perhaps?).  So no matter how many instances of a class there are, the memory will only keep one copy of the methods in that instance.  So as long as I am not changing the properties then multiple instances (one for each player) won't really effect the memory.

Comment: It is always the case that the code for methods is not instantiated per class. This is regardless of whether you get or set properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am currently working on a game for fun and had a question about c# performance.

Please read the [Speed rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). However you do have a rare example where it might mater, if only due to the sheer scale.

> I prefer Method 2, but I am worried about instantiating a class (PlayerMover) for each player (perhaps 100 players). Will it then keep 100 copies of PlayerMover in memory (one for each player)?

Yes, creating a new Instance will consume memory for each instance. And they can not be collected while the Player wrapping around them can not be collected. I could not find a definition of the class PlayerMover online. Some classes do not work properly if you do not keep a instance for each player. Some only work properly if you keep one instance around (Random is a good example). But I could find no information one way or the other, so I asume it is the bulk of "neutral" classes.

Unless there is some actuall technical need for one over the other, I would prefer wichever one is easier to read and code. For me readability always takes precendence over minor performance impacts.

Comment: Yes, readability is why I prefer Method 2, PlayerMover would be some custom class/method to move a player.  Is the memory keeping copies of the instantiated class or simply adding small amounts of memory just referencing that class which already exists in memory? If that makes sense.

Comment: @Tyler You create a new isntance. And then assign a Reference to it to your variable. So actually both. | There are very few cases where stuff is designed to go towards one instance - the Singleton variant of the Factory Pattern. Dependency Properties. Static/class fields. Strings and their interning. | This might even be the rare case where you could go for a static instance of PlayerMover. Unfortunately we can not tell you one way or the other, as we do not know what player move even *does*.

Comment: Yeah, that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first way, only one `PlayerMover` will be instanciated.

In the second one, none will be instanciated, as you don't create instances of your `Player` class. But if you do, there will be as much `PlayerMover` as `Player` instances.

Comment: yes, and I'm wondering if the multiple instances of the `PlayerMover` will be added to memory or if only a single `PlayerMover` will be in memory according to Method 2

Comment: If there are no instances of Player in `_players`, the whole foreach would be kinda pointless.

Comment: In method 2, the multiple instances will be added to memory.